# qtserialport... error: ‘Q_NULLPTR’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: qt, c++11, serial-port, g++, ubuntu-16.04

Am trying to install qt creator following these sequences suggested by a hardware provider...

```
sudo apt-get install libudev-dev
git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qtserialport.git && cd qtserialport
git checkout origin/old/5.2
cd .. 
mkdir qtserialport-build && cd qtserialport-build 
qmake ../qtserialport/qtserialport.pro 
make && sudo make install

cd ../qtserialport/ && git checkout origin/5.3
cd ../qtserialport-build/
make
```

But am getting errors at the last make:

```
In file included from /home/polar/soft/lib/qt/qtserialport/src/serialport/qserialport.cpp:45:0:
/home/polar/soft/lib/qt/qtserialport/src/serialport/qserialport.h:190:44: 

error: ‘Q_NULLPTR’ was not declared in this scope
     explicit QSerialPort(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
                                            ^
```

On stackoverflow some suggested to add `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x`, others `CONFIG += c++11` to the `.pro` file. These did not work for me.... In fact there are at least two .pro files... which one I need amendment?

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Why are you trying to build qtserialport if you just need to install QtCreator?  Ubuntu has a version of QtCreator in their archives already, so you can just install it with `apt-get install qtcreator`

Answer (score 2):

the Q_NULLPTR is declared int the header file qserialportglobal.h ,so you just need to do is  #include  in the qserialport.h file